.net framework 4.8 publish via cmd - missing publish.htm
I want to automate the clickonce publishing process, via command line as I have multiple targets to publish to. I'm trying to get cmd line execution to do the same as publish button in VS, but with no luck so far, there is always publish.htm missing.
here's the publish configuration:


here is the relevant part of csproj:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{D24583D6-0B21-40D8-8EF1-C8A781B29226}</ProjectGuid>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>namespace</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>assemblyname</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
        <TargetFrameworkProfile />
        <IsWebBootstrapper>true</IsWebBootstrapper>
        <PublishUrl>C:\project\repos\repo\DEPLOY\client\</PublishUrl>
        <Install>true</Install>
        <InstallFrom>Web</InstallFrom>
        <UpdateEnabled>true</UpdateEnabled>
        <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
        <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
        <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
        <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
        <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
        <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
        <InstallUrl>http://localhost:1180/client/</InstallUrl>
        <UpdateUrl>http://localhost:1180/client/</UpdateUrl>
        <ProductName>app</ProductName>
        <PublisherName>company</PublisherName>
        <SuiteName>Suite</SuiteName>
        <MinimumRequiredVersion>4.0.6.0</MinimumRequiredVersion>
        <CreateWebPageOnPublish>true</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
        <WebPage>publish.htm</WebPage>
        <OpenBrowserOnPublish>false</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
        <ApplicationRevision>100</ApplicationRevision>
        <ApplicationVersion>4.0.6.100</ApplicationVersion>
        <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
        <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
        <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
      </PropertyGroup>
      ...
</Project>

As i have multiple locations that I need to generate a client package, I want to run this configuration via command line and automate the process.
but when I run this:
msbuild GFFRNT.csproj /t:Publish  /p:PublishDir="C:\project\repos\repo\DEPLOY\client\cmd" /p:InstallUrl="http://localhost:1180/client/" /p:UpdateUrl="http://localhost:1180/client/"

the publish.htm is missing, I would expect to configuration to be pulled from csproj. and rest to be overridable via parameters passed to msbuild.
What am I doing wrong?

The documentation for the command line doesn't indicate that WebPage is a supported property. You could run msbuild GFFRNT.csproj /pp and search the resulting output for any $(WebPage) references to see if you can figure out if it even used or not.
